# How can I get a list of Azure AD usernames in Power BI / SQL Server Query based on the users GUIDs?

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, powerbi

Have a table in SQL Server with a column "ModifiedBy" with Azure AD users GUIDs.

How can I get back the usernames - in an SQL query?

Actually need this for a Power BI report - so a conversion function in Power BI would also work.

Comment: You won't be able to do this with SQL alone. Something *else* will need to interrogate the AD.

Comment: I agree. It might be best to write an external process, say in Azure Automation or something, that pulls down every GUID/UPN combination into a SQL Server table so that you can join to it. Here's a simple example of using powershell to extract to a CSV https://www.ntweekly.com/2020/09/10/export-azure-ad-users-with-powershell-to-a-csv-file/

Comment: Here's a solution in M that should be able to pull AAD info directly into a table in Power BI, although it's quite complex https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Get-Data-Active-Directory/m-p/73726

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PowerShell script to get the list of Azure AD users with GUID, Username and Display name. This data can be exported to a CSV File.

Please use the below PowerShell script :

```
Connect-AzureAD 
get-azureaduser | Select-Object ObjectId,UserPrincipalName,DisplayName | export-csv csv-file-path
```

This script will fetch all the users in the Azure AD with GUID, Username and Display name and export it to a CSV file.

[image]

Now you can import the data from your CSV file to SQL Server or Azure SQL Database by following any of the methods described in the below document :

[Import data from Excel to SQL - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=azuresqldb-current)

You can use JOIN to query the two tables and get the usernames

Comment: Though not a "direct" answer- it's a useful solution - so thanks! and accepted as answer